# eslint-laoder failing the build even if the failOnError set to false

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, webpack-4, eslint-config-airbnb

Target?

Build should be successful even if there are linting errors

Problem?

even if I have set the `failOnError` to false build is failing if there is even a single linting error.

[image: error screen shot]

```
"eslint-loader": "4.0.2"
```

**Webpack Config**

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = env => {
  return {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src/js/server.js"),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "server.bundle.js"
    },

    target: 'node',

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["babel-loader",
            {
              loader: 'eslint-loader',
              options: {
                fix: false,
                emitWarning: false,
                emitError: false,
                failOnError: false,
                failOnWarning: false,
                quiet: true,
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
};
```